# Iron Router action not being called after adding waitOn

Tags: meteor, iron-router

So I'm trying to use waitOn so my app doesn't render my templates until the data is ready.

here is my code:

```
Router.configure

    loadingTemplate: 'loading'

Router.map ->

    @route 'burgers',
        path   : '/burgers'
        waitOn : -> Meteor.subscribe 'burgers'
        data   : -> burgers: BurgerList.find {}, sort: votes: -1
        action : ->
            if @ready()
                @render 'burgers'
```

After adding the waitOn function nothing is being rendered. The action function isnt even being called.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you published **burgers** ? You have to publish burgers using **Meteor.publish()**

Comment: Will it change anything if you erase `action`?

Comment: **action** is optional, By default it will render template specific to the route. In this case without action it will render template named **burgers**.

Comment: Yeah you got it @SG_ . I never published burgers! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to publish **burgers**,  Use **Meteor.publish()**.